# Can a prepositional phrase be an object complement?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases, object-complements

If yes, how not to confuse a prepositional phrase as an object complement and as an adverb. E.g "I consider you as a friend". Is "as a friend" an adverb implying "I'm your friend and I consider you from this position" Or an object complement meaning "I consider you my friend". Does the accurate meaning depend on a context?

Answer (score 1):

The latter.

> *I consider you as a friend.*

It's not the whole preposition phrase "as a friend" that is predicative complement of "consider", but just the noun phrase "a friend".

"A friend" can be analysed as a 'predicative oblique' because it is complement of a preposition instead of being related directly to the verb.

Note that some grammars call the "as phrase" itself a 'marked predicative complement'.

Comment: It's also possible to have a PP (preposition phrase) functioning as predicative complement where it has a clause as predicand. For example "He considers taking advice beneath his dignity", where the sub clause "taking advice" is predicand for the the predicative complement PP "beneath his dignity". If this is of interest to you, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Can " as a friend " be considered as an adverb?

Comment: @PetroProbka You mean adverbial. No: "consider" requires an obligatory complement, but adverbials are always optional. As I said in my answer, the PP may be considered a 'marked predicative complement'.

Comment: It's not predicative 100% it doesn't follow an auxiliary verb. Consider - predicate, you- object, as a friend - adverb or object complement

Comment: @PetroProbka  Not all predicatives follow an auxiliary verb. Consider "He seemed a nice guy" / "She felt lonely", both predicative but no auxiliary verb in sight. "Consider" also takes PCs, as seen in your example. I've already told you that there is no adverbial in your example. And I've already explained that "a friend" is predicative complement of "consider"

Comment: @PetroProbka Further, objective PCs can occur without an auxiliary verb being present, for example "They elected him **president**" / "We painted our house **white**".

Comment: A transitive verb requires an direct object so there it is but a prepositional phrase can be used in the role of an adverb or an adjective or an objective complement depending on a context

Comment: @PetroProbka Preposition phrases do **not** function as adverbs or adjectives. Who told you that? They function as modifiers or complements. I explained in my answer that it is just "a friend" that is PC of "consider", **not** the whole PP.

Comment: A prepositional phrase can play the role of an adverb like "I fell in snow" In snow is the adverb expressed by the prepositional phrase

Comment: @PetroProbka No: it's a preposition phrase functioning as an **adverbial**. 'Adverb' is a word class (part of speech), while 'adverbial' is the corresponding function. I have given you the answer to your original question. Now take it on board.

Comment: +1 for your analysis of the only 'sensible' interpretation of OP's sentence, but I believe what he's asking about *now in the comments* is the (very unlikely) alternative interpretation where "consider" means something like "think about" instead of "evaluate to be."  So, OP is asking if, in **this** version (which would mean *"I think about you as (i.e. in the manner that) a friend [would],"* the prepositional phrase would function as an adverbial. It seems like the answer to that would be "yes," with the caveat that no one would actually interpret the sentence that way.

Comment: @PetroProbka **consider** has multiple definitions (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consider). The way it is being used in your sentence is as an *"attributive ditransitive verb"* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb). This would be definition 4. If I understand your followup question right, are you asking about the alternative interpretation of the same sentence in which "consider" uses definition 3?

Comment: @PetroProbka I'm assuming you're only asking about the second possibility out of academic interest? If you're actually trying to convey the meaning of "I'm looking at you/thinking about you from the perspective that a friend would look at/think about you," it would be better to rephrase the sentence, as no one would ordinarily interpret it to mean that.